# .htaccess rewrite file path favicon.ico to core/favicon.ico

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am doing something wrong with writing my `.htaccess` syntax and what exactly I am unsure.

I have a file called `/core/favicon.ico`.

Now I want when the browser requests `/favicon.ico` it to have the server display: `/core/favicon.ico`.

The contents of my `.htaccess` is currently

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ core/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
    
    RewriteRule ^favicon.ico core/favicon.ico [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

The previous rewrite rule is needed for the functioning of my system.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ core/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And that rule works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ core/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
>
> RewriteRule ^favicon.ico core/favicon.ico [NC,L]
> ```

You've basically just got your rules in the wrong order. Presumably `/favicon.ico` does not exist, so the first rule rewrites the request to `core/index.php?url=favicon.ico` first and processing stops.

You need to reverse the two rules (and backslash-escape the dot and add the end-of-string anchor). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico$ core/favicon.ico [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ core/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

*Aside:* This does not rewrite requests for the "homepage" (the document root), so presumably you have something else that handles that? Otherwise, I would expect you need to set the `DirectoryIndex` accordingly at the top of the file. For example:

```
DirectoryIndex /core/index.php
```

Note that the `url` parameter will be absent for such requests (to the "homepage").

Comment: Thank you! This works great! Well the homepage is covered already. Simply empty calls get to see x. And that works fine :-)